# Django Problem with count of model objects

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I need to disable adding new users in the admin panel once the number of users exceeds a particular value. The code below works to remove the "add user" button when I test it with hard coded integers. However, this line does not appear to be returning the count of users without hard coding a count: `usercount = CustomUser.objects.count()`

Any ideas for getting the count of users already added?

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db.models import Count
from django.db.models.signals import post_save


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    employee_type = models.ForeignKey(Group, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, default=1)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=True)

# disable add new user in the admin panel
class RemoveAddNew(admin.ModelAdmin):
    usercount = CustomUser.objects.count()

    if usercount > 5:
      def has_add_permission(self, request, obj=None):
          return False
```

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser, RemoveAddNew

class CustomUserAdmin(RemoveAddNew, UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = CustomUser
    list_display = ['username', 'email', 'full_name', 'age', 'is_staff', 'is_active']
    fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets + (
        (None, {'fields': ('full_name', 'age', )}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = UserAdmin.add_fieldsets + (
        (None, {'fields': ('email','full_name', 'age', 'employee_type', 'is_active')}),
    )

admin.site.register(CustomUser,CustomUserAdmin)
```

Comment: The issue appears to be that I need to define usercount as an instance variable and move the conditional inside of the method. So far, as a newbie, I am having difficulty figuring out how to correctly defining "usercount" as an instance variable of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you over code it. My solution is simpler and shorter:

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = CustomUser
    list_display = ['username', 'email', 'full_name', 'age', 'is_staff', 'is_active']
    fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets + (
        (None, {'fields': ('full_name', 'age', )}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = UserAdmin.add_fieldsets + (
        (None, {'fields': ('email','full_name', 'age', 'employee_type', 'is_active')}),
    )

    def has_add_permission(self, request):

        return CustomUser.objects.count() < 6

admin.site.register(CustomUser,CustomUserAdmin)
```